# SQL database and permisions (via PHP)

Tags: php, sql, database, permissions

I am creating a web site which, among other things, databases pictures. For simplicity lets say that every picture can have a description and a file path, and this is stored in a table, like so

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS picture
(
  ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  description VARCHAR(150),
  file VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Rather than storing all these pictures in a single location and assigning arbitrary file paths, I want the user to be able to upload the pictures via ftp to a unix account and create their own directory hierarchy. This way they can use ftp/sftp/scp to copy them, or ssh and, use other Linux programs, like imagemagik or zip. Or to change permissions for pictures (see below)

Now I realize this will cause problems if the user decides to delete pictures or move them, but I suppose there are ways around this (database does not guarantee pictures will be there, write protect pictures, re-implement `mv`/`rm`...)

I have very little databasing experience. I wanted to know if this is advisable. Specifically, whether its good to use [Linux file permisions](http://www.thewebhostinghero.com/tutorials/linux-file-permissions.html) as database permissions. So for example, user `Manderly` could create group `MJ12` and add users `WSimons`, `BPage`, and `ANavarre` to it, then on the website those users would have access to these pictures (not automatically I know, but scripted via PHP) AND they could sftp/ftp/scp them as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting answers to other questions from the community, I can now answer my own question.

It is obviously possible to implement this in PHP by using `/etc/passwd`, getting file permissions via `int fileperms ( string $filename )`, and either updating the database with those, or using them as a check before allowing access to files. This however is overkill. It is easier to simply use [suPHP](http://www.suphp.org/Home.html).

> suPHP is a tool for executing PHP scripts with the permissions of
>   their owners. It consists of an Apache module (mod_suphp) and a setuid
>   root binary (suphp) that is called by the Apache module to change the
>   uid of the process executing the PHP interpreter.

As to whether it's advisable, general consensus at SO seems to be that one should only implement such a server if it serves a purpose. This can be taken to be mean "it's generally not advisable"